# require_once failed to open stream even tho on other pages it works well with no errors

Tags: php, stream, require

Im having such difficulty over something that is probably not such a big problem.

I keep getting the error: Warning: require(models/match.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

Now i know it does work as in the same directory at the same file level it has worked when just this code but when i put it in with the other bits of code it fails

code:

```
    <?php
define('KICKOFF_REL','../../../../');

set_include_path(KICKOFF_REL);  




require 'models/match.php';



$league_id = 1; //'premier league';
require 'models/league.php';
$theMenuLeagueObj = new league();   
$league_details = $theMenuLeagueObj->fetch_league($league_id);


//require 'models/match.php';
$theMatchObj = new match(); //Create match object
$allAvaliableMatches = $theMatchObj->fetch_all_active_matches($league_details['league_name']);
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th scope="col">'. $league_details['league_name'] . '</th>';
    echo '<th scope="col">'. $league_details['league_name'] . '</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
foreach($allAvaliableMatches as $thematch){




    echo '<tr>
    <td>'. $thematch['home_team'] . " v " . $thematch['away_team'] . '</td>
    <td>Sunday Games</td></tr>';

    }

    echo '</table>';
```

Comment: What are 'the other bits of code'?

Answer (score 0):

The other files have the correct path, this one does not.

That is the reason for which the others worked while this one didn't.

Use `realpath('model/match.php')` to see what *full path* PHP uses when evaluating the *relative path* you gave it.

Comment: And I recommend this also; 

`set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(realpath(__DIR__ . '/path/to/filedir'),
    get_include_path())));`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use require,require_once,include or include_once at that time you must check whether path is correct or not. to check that you have to just **ctrl+left click**. if path is correct then the will be open otherwise it will not.

Comment: CTRL+Left-Click? In what IDE? OP didn't mention an IDE.

Comment: i'm using NetBeans so it work in it. and it may also work in eclipse and dreamviewer.

Comment: My point was the fact that your answer is misleading because it does not mention in what applications/IDEs this would work. Besides the fact that many people do not use either NetBeans Eclipse or DreamWeaver.